# How to retrieve open Journal entries

Tags: netsuite

can any one please suggest how to retrieve the open journal entries using suite script. iam able to retrieve journal entries but facing issue while applying filter on posting period as I need to retrieve the journal entries for where the posting period is open. 
for ex: if the accounting period is locked for Sep 2016 then I need to retrieve the journal entries only for open month that is for current month Oct 2016.
any suggestions are welcome and highly appreciated as is impacting our release.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `postingperiod` filter in saved search to pull only for the current month's posting period.

For example, if current/open month's posting period internalid is 266

```
var jes = nlapiSearchRecord('journalentry', null, ['postingperiod', 'anyof', 266])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get JE's in ALL open periods, you can use a join with `accountingperiod`, like this:

```
var journals = nlapiSearchRecord('journalentry', null, ['accountingperiod.closed', 'is', 'F']);
```